# Generating Random Number method

Tags: java, methods, random, generator

I need help writing a method that will return a random 4 digit number with no repetitions. I am not allowed to use string in any way...

This is what i have so far and the line where ran. is involved, im getting an error: ran cannot be resolved

```
public static int generateSecretNumber() {
    Random r = new Random();
    int x = r.nextInt(1000);;    
    x = x + 1000;  
    return x;
```

Comment: By no repititions i mean 4 distinct numbers, I.E.: 1234 not 1233 etc.

Comment: Never write "I'm getting an error" when you can write "I'm getting this error: `ran cannot be resolved`."

Comment: ty, still having the same issue, plus, how do i make it 4 distinct numbers??

Comment: Take a look at this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-a-javascript-array

Answer (score 2):

You can generate 4 independent numbers.

1) generate number A between 1 and 9

2) generate number B between 0 and 9 and different from A

3) generate number C between 0 and 9 and different from A and B

4) generate number D between 0 and 9 and different from A, B and C

Now your number is ABCD or

```
1000*A + 100*B + 10*C + D
```

Full code:

```
public static int generateSecretNumber() {
    Random ran = new Random();
    int a, b, c, d;

    a = ran.nextInt(9) + 1; //1-9

    do {
        b = ran.nextInt(10); //0-9
    } while(b==a);

    do {
        c = ran.nextInt(10); //0-9
    } while(c==a || c==b);

    do {
        d = ran.nextInt(10); //0-9
    } while(d==c || d==b || d==a);

    return 1000*a + 100*b + 10*c + d;
}
```

Comment: Im still getting "ran cannot be resolved" and how do i make it that the numbers generated are all distinct?

Comment: Would this be considered as using string though? if not, how can i implement it into my method so that i can call it back later?

Comment: you can convert number to string by (number+"") - simply add empty string

Comment: Im not allowed to use any string at all

Comment: Well, this doesnt use any strings at all. Ill write the whole method with header and return for you.

Comment: This will work and is very helpful, but I don't like the idea of having a do-loop per digit. What if you wanted to change the problem to do the same, but for 10 digits? Are you going to just keep adding do-loops? Not the most flexible approach you could have.

Comment: You can add an array of boolean values, witch will indicate weather the number was used or not, or you can have a List of used numbers. Then you can generate your numbers in a cycle.

Answer (score 2):

The line:

```
int x = + ran.nextInt(1000);
```

should read

```
int x = r.nextInt(1000);
```

Another thing - you say you want to generate a random 4 digit number with no repetitions.
This could take a while as it is perfectly ok for a random number generator to return the same  number multiple times, in the same way that when you flip a coin you can get 4 heads in a row.

Answer (score 1):

Generate 4 random digits between 0 and 9 (argument to `nextInt`: 10).  Keep track of all 4 digits.  If any of them are the same, then generate another random digit.  Then construct your final number using the digits.

Additionally, if you are going to declare your `Random` variable `r`, then use `r.nextInt(10)` not `ran.nextInt(10)`.

Answer (score 1):

For a 4 digit random number with distinct digits you could just shuffle a collection.

```
List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0);
do{
    Collections.shuffle(numbers);
} while (0 == numbers.get(0));

System.out.println(numbers.subList(0, 4));
```

Comment: This is a very unique idea and I like it. It wouldn't work if you needed a number longer than 10 digits, however, I suppose the same is true of using a 32-bit integer. +1 for creativity

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of different ways you could do this to get distinct numbers. I advise something like the following:

```
public static int generateSecretNumber(int digitLength) {
    Random ran = new Random();
    int randDigit[digitLength];
    int finalNum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < digitLength; i++){
        randDigit[i] = ran.nextInt(10);
        int j = 0;
        while(j < i){
            if(randDigit[j] == randDigit[i]){
                randDigit[i] = ran.nextInt(10);
                j = 0;
                continue;
            }
            j++;
        }

    }

    for(int i = 0; i < digitLength; i++){
        finalNum = finalNum + (randDigit[i] * Math.pow(10, i));
    }

    return finalNum;
}
```

Comment: i get "cannot be resolved as a variable" for randDigit. how would i fi this??

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo in the declaration of the array. Will edit original right now, but the array declaration "int randDigits[digitLength];" should be "int randDigit[digitLength];"